# Error when updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try update my Android Sudio I get this message:

```
Temp. directory: C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Temp\

+----------------
| A file operation failed.
| This might be due to a file being locked by another
| application. Please try closing any application
| that uses the files being updated then press 'Retry'.
+----------------


com.intellij.updater.RetryException: Cannot delete file C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar
    at com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.replaceUpdated(BaseUpdateAction.java:40)
    at com.intellij.updater.UpdateZipAction.doApply(UpdateZipAction.java:199)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:140)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch$3.forEach(Patch.java:198)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:248)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:194)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:86)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:77)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstallImpl(Runner.java:307)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:268)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.access$000(Runner.java:18)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner$2.execute(Runner.java:258)
    at com.intellij.updater.SwingUpdaterUI$7.run(SwingUpdaterUI.java:230)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 9):

The file `Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar` is probably in use by some JVM process (shown as `java.exe` in Task Manager).

Solution that worked for me was to close the updater and close all `java.exe` processes in Task Manager, then open Android Studio and try updating once more. This time the update should go all the way through.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround:

```
1-Close Android Studio.
2-Right-click "Android Studio" icon and select "Run as administrator".
3-Go to "Help->Check for Update..."
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for updating anything without the rule of updater. And the rule must be administrator or super user.

P.S.

As how it's name, updating is updating, renewing or deleting. Then it knows what it takes.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the exact error you getting. I left my PC on over night and clicked retry and it worked. Very strange. I also tried using:

handle - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx
and
Process explorer - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

to check what is locking that file and they both showed nothing. That is when I clicked retry and it worked